# how to define AttributeSet parameter for extended layout

Tags: android

I am having trouble understanding how to instantiate a custom layout in code. Specifically I do not know how to define the required `AttributeSet` parameter.

I have gone through the official docs but could not wrap my head around it :

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html

In my activity, i instantiate it with :

```
new MyCustomLayout(getActivity(), attrs)
```

**But how do i define `attrs`?**

***MyCustomLayout.java***

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LinearLayout implements
        OnClickListener {

    ...
    ...

    public MyCustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycustomxmllayout, this, true);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

***mycustomxmllayout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:lines="1"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should define your custom attributes in the `res/values/attrs.xml`, just add `<declare-styleable>`, for example:

```
   <declare-styleable name="MyCustomLayout">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="buttonPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
```

Now you can set your custom attrs via xml, like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <your.package.name.MyCustomLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:buttonPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your constructor you can grab that attrs:

```
public MyCustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.MyCustomLayout,
        0, 0);

   try {
       mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyCustomLayout_showText, false);
       mButtonPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyCustomLayout_buttonPosition, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
}
```

If you want to set your attrs programmatically, you should create public getters/setters for that:

```
private boolean mShowText;
private Integer mButtonPos;

public void setButtonPos(int pos) {
    mButtonPos = pos;
}

public void setShowText(boolean showText) {
    mShowText = showText;
}
```

After that you can set your attrs programmatically:

```
MyCustomLayout layout = new MyCustomLayout(getActivity());
layout.setButtonPos(0);
layout.setShowText(true);
```

Comment: that's interesting. I was hoping to simply reuse the existing attributes of the framework's LinearLayout. That is why i extended it. I do not want to defined any custom attributes. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: What attrs do you want to use, for example? And where do you want to use it?

Comment: I just need the `AttributeSet` parameter to instantiate the layout in my activity i.e. the second parameter in `new MyCustomLayout(getActivity(), attrs)`. So whatever is the minimum required to get it working is all i am looking for. I am guessing this means `layout_height` and `layout_width`. If i can skip the parameter all together, it would be even better.

Comment: The constructor that have `attrs` parameter is only used when you create your layout from xml, not programmatically. If you create your layout programmatically you should also set it properties programmatically.

Comment: So instead of using `super(context, attrs)` in my constructor, are you saying i can simply use `super(context)` and then set the required attributes using `setLayoutParams()` ?